# Need help converting PowerShell to C# code

Tags: c#, powershell

So i have this powershell code:

```
try{
    $ComputerWMIObject = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -ComputerName "$oldComputerName" -Authentication 6
    if ( $ComputerWMIObject ){
        $result = $ComputerWMIObject.Rename("$newComputerName", $ADUserPassword , $ADUserName )
        switch($result.ReturnValue)
        {
            0 {
                if ( $Restart.IsChecked ) {
                    Get-WmiObject Win32_OperatingSystem -ComputerName "$oldComputerName" | ForEach-Object {$restart = $_.Win32Shutdown(6)}
                    $ResultText.Text = "Computer $oldComputerName was renamed to $newComputerName and restarted"
                } else {
                    $ResultText.Text = "Computer $oldComputerName was renamed to $newComputerName restart computer to finish"
                }

            }
            5 { $ResultText.Text = "Computer was not renamed. Please check if you have admin permissions (ReturnCode 5)" }
            default { $ResultText.Text = "ReturnCode $($result.ReturnValue)"}
        }
    }else{
        $ResultText.Text = "Couldn't create WMI Object on $oldComputerName"
    }
}catch{
    $ResultText.Text = $_
}
```

I'm trying to convert this to C# and can't find a way to do this. I just don't understand how to create WMI object.

It would be very helpful if you can post and example on how to do this. 
I've read this [Remotely change computer name for a Windows Server 2008 machine using C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207411/remotely-change-computer-name-for-a-windows-server-2008-machine-using-c) topic. And it throws an exception may be its because of this line:

```
Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy
```

I'm using System.Net.Security namespace and as it's stated in comment PacketPrivacy exists only there.

Since I can't ask there because I have low rating I've asked again.

Would be grateful if any one can help me.

PS: I know this can be done using NETDOM but I would prefer using WMI object.

**ADDED:**

I'm trying to use this:

```
var remoteControlObject = new ManagementPath
{
    ClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem",
    Server = oldName,
    Path = oldName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" + oldName + "'",
    NamespacePath = "\\\\" + oldName + "\\root\\cimv2"
};

var conn = new ConnectionOptions
{
    Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
    Username = accountWithPermissions.Domain + "\\" + accountWithPermissions.UserName,
    Password = accountWithPermissions.Password
};

var remoteScope = new ManagementScope(remoteControlObject, conn);

var remoteSystem = new ManagementObject(remoteScope, remoteControlObject, null);

ManagementBaseObject newRemoteSystemName = remoteSystem.GetMethodParameters("Rename");
var methodOptions = new InvokeMethodOptions();

newRemoteSystemName.SetPropertyValue("Name", newName);
newRemoteSystemName.SetPropertyValue("UserName", accountWithPermissions.UserName);
newRemoteSystemName.SetPropertyValue("Password", accountWithPermissions.Password);

ManagementBaseObject outParams = remoteSystem.InvokeMethod("Rename", newRemoteSystemName, null);
```

And I get this error **Server RPC is unavailable. (Exception HRESULT: 0x800706BA)** here:

```
ManagementBaseObject newRemoteSystemName = remoteSystem.GetMethodParameters("Rename");
```

**ADDED2:**

Ok, I guess I found out what causes an error.

i've changed original **conn** User name from

```
Username = oldName + "\\" + accountWithPermissions.UserName,
```

to

```
Username = accountWithPermissions.Domain + "\\" + accountWithPermissions.UserName,
```

and error happens, if I use old code I get ACCESS_IS_DENIED and that's correct because that user doesn't have rights.

So what's wrong if I use Domain\User may be I should change **NamespacePath** in **remoteControlObject** to be able to work with domain user authentication?

Comment: Everything you need will be in the [System.Management](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Management%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) namespace.

Comment: Still have **Server RPC is unavailable. (Exception HRESULT: 0x800706BA)** I get this here ManagementBaseObject newRemoteSystemName = remoteSystem.GetMethodParameters("Rename"); will add code I'm trying to implement in a sec.

Comment: I don't know how you're initialising `ConnectionOptions`, doesn't seem to follow the reference. You probably need to use `ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate` when connecting to the remote computer.

Comment: ConnectionOptions exists only in code I showed so I guess I'm not initialising it :/ Can you be more clear how should I initialise it ? I'm new to this so I've just copy-pasted code. And tried to run.

Comment: I guess i found out myself. Added this conn.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate; but exception still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find a way resolve this issue and no one seems to have an answer.

So I've solved this by using **NETDOM** when **Server RPC is unavailable. (Exception HRESULT: 0x800706BA)** actually any error happens I will add access denied check so it won't try NETDOM when this happens;

```
var remoteControlObject = new ManagementPath
{
    ClassName = "Win32_ComputerSystem",
    Server = oldName,
    Path = oldName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" + oldName + "'",
    NamespacePath = "\\\\" + oldName + "\\root\\cimv2"
};

string domain = accountWithPermissions.Domain;
string user = accountWithPermissions.UserName;

var conn = new ConnectionOptions
{
    Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
    Username = domain + "\\" + accountWithPermissions.UserName,
    Password = accountWithPermissions.Password
};
var remoteScope = new ManagementScope(remoteControlObject, conn);

var remoteSystem = new ManagementObject(remoteScope, remoteControlObject, null);
try
{
    ManagementBaseObject newRemoteSystemName = remoteSystem.GetMethodParameters("Rename");
    newRemoteSystemName.SetPropertyValue("Name", newName);
    newRemoteSystemName.SetPropertyValue("UserName", accountWithPermissions.UserName);
    newRemoteSystemName.SetPropertyValue("Password", accountWithPermissions.Password);
    ManagementBaseObject outParams = remoteSystem.InvokeMethod("Rename", newRemoteSystemName, null);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    this.Res.Inlines.Add(string.Format("Ошибка:\n" + e.Message + "\n"));
    this.Res.Inlines.Add(string.Format("Пробуем переименовать используя NETDOM\n"));
    bool restart = false;
    PowerNETDOM(oldName, newName, accountWithPermissions, restart);
}
```

**Server RPC is unavailable. (Exception HRESULT: 0x800706BA)** is happening not because my changes to the script. This error if fired only by few PC's as I found out it can happen in many cases more about this here: [Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11330874/get-wmiobject-the-rpc-server-is-unavailable-exception-from-hresult-0x800706) . And changing settings on a remote PC makes me go and check the settings directly from that PC. In that case I can just rename PC not even trying to find out what this happening. That's why I do use **NETDOM** because for some reason it doesn't have problems renaming that PC remotely.

```
    private static void PowerNETDOM(String oldName, String newName, NetworkCredential accountWithPermissions, bool restart)
    {
        using (PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            PowerShellInstance.AddScript
                (
                    "param($Restart,$oldComputerName,$newComputerName,$ADUserPassword,$ADUserName);" +
                    "function ConvertTo-Encoding ([string]$From, [string]$To){" +
                    "   Begin{ $encFrom = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($from);$encTo = [System.Text.Encoding]::GetEncoding($to); }" +
                    "   Process{ $bytes = $encTo.GetBytes($_);$bytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Convert($encFrom, $encTo, $bytes);$encTo.GetString($bytes)}" +
                    "}" +
                    "$tmp = NETDOM RENAMECOMPUTER $oldComputerName /NewName:$newComputerName /ud:$ADUserName /pd:$ADUserPassword /Force $res_text | ConvertTo-Encoding \"cp866\" \"windows-1251\";" +
                    "$tmp > C:\\Temp\\rename.txt;$tmp;"
                );

            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("restart", restart);
            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("newComputerName", newName);
            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("oldComputerName", oldName.ToString());
            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("ADUserPassword", accountWithPermissions.Password);
            PowerShellInstance.AddParameter("ADUserName", accountWithPermissions.Domain + "\\" + accountWithPermissions.UserName);

            PowerShellInstance.Invoke();
        }

    }
```